# ubuntu 23.04 overwrite my personal .Xmodmap settings

Tags: keyboard, locale, xmodmap

I have been using personal .Xmodmap keyboard settings since Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. But in Ubuntu 23.04 the OS constantly overwrites these settings by LOCALE ones and I need to restart them by "xmodmap .Xmodmap" each time. How to fix my personal keyboard .Xmodmap settings?

Comment: Are you using Wayland? If you are, logging in to "Ubuntu on Xorg" instead might make a difference.

Comment: .Xmodmap only works with the XServer. So Gunnars comment is the solution

Comment: I'm using Xorg. The problem is that I fix my personal settings trough "xmodmap .Xmodmap". It works fine, but after some time (half an hour, an hour, ...) the system overwrite may settings. It happens only in 23.04. I have used it in 12.04,16.04 and 20.04 without problems